# What's the equivalent to Mac's "control+command+x" in Windows? (sublime text 2)

Tags: windows, macos, sublimetext2

It's a command to run the code to check which browsers do not need CSS specifications.
Is there a place where I can find the key-map for the two OSs?

Comment: This is not a default key combination in Sublime - it must be assigned via a plugin.

Comment: @MattDMo I am in Emmet (old Zen Code) and it is for eliminating the unnecessary entries given for -box-shadow.

Comment: @MattDMo Just got it. It's Ctrl Alt X. Thanks man.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

It should be `Alt`+`Ctrl`+`X`. All `Cmd` shortcuts transforms to `Ctrl`, and all `Ctrl` ones transforms to `Alt` under Windows or Linux, if their author hasn't set some specific.